How to view raw image of Image Sensor like OV5640?
I'm using the OV5640 image sensor with an FPGA in JPEG mode with 720p 30 fps. Currently, I can send images via Ethernet and view them on my PC. Now, I want to capture raw RGB images directly from the OV5640 without any processing from the image sensor processor and formatter. And send it via Ethernet (gigabit) to PC.

Which registers do I need to configure to achieve this with 720p or less and 15 fps?

How can I view these raw images or videos on my PC?
For this I am asking about software to view RAW picture/video on PC, I am able to transmit data via 1G Ethernet using FPGA.



Do you have a link to a datasheet or user manual?

https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/LightImaging/OV5640_datasheet.pdf

I think have found enough information to attempt an answer for the first question about the configuration resister values. For the second question How can I view these raw images or videos on my PC? are you asking about the software to run on the PC and/or the FPGA design to allow the images to be transferred to the PC?

I am asking about software to view RAW picture/video on PC, I am able to transmit data via 1G ethernet using FPGA.

For the software, you don't even say how you captured the raw data into file. You can likely be able to convert it into some file format you can import to image editing programs understanding RAW from different cameras. Or do the Bayer colour matrix decoding yourself with some tool.

@Justme I am reading RAW RGB data from OV5640 and send it to PC via Ethernet, and on PC I am receiving those packets using python and store payload only in .bin file. Now I want to play that video or view each frame using some software to see if I correctly capture frames.

@optiplex91 Since you say I am reading RAW RGB data from OV5640 does that mean you have answered the question about the OV5640 register configuration settings to get raw format images for 720p or less and 15 fps, and the only outstanding question is about using some software on the PC to play video / view each frame?

@ChesterGillon yes I am able to get 720p 15 fps raw data by disabling jpeg registers, changing PLL registers and changing format control registers

You can view raw RGB image data in programming languages like Matlab/python or in image viewer software such as imagej. Take your pick.

@user1850479 Thanks a lot and what software is best for raw RGB video data (multiple frames stored in same file)
